# Running selenium from a built jar does not recognize ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I have wrote out a few classes and tests which work fine when I execute them right out of intellij. But when I build a jar and try and run the tests, I keep getting that Chrome driver is not found. I have a base class that I setup the WebDriver in:

```
package mac.chrome;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

/*
* @param WebDriver driver
* @param Object formID dynamic form ID field
* @param WebDriverWait allows to wait for elements using the By class
*
* */
public class Driver {

    static public WebDriver driver;
    static public Object formID;
    static public WebDriverWait wait;

    public Driver(){

        System.setProperty(
                "webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "./chromedriver"
        );

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        formID = null;
        wait   = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    }


}
```

I have tried both using System.setProperty and adding the vm options to specify chrome driver when the jar launches:

```
/Users/mpmadmin/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/mpmadmin/IdeaProjects/mchnSelenium/chromedriver -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /Users/mpmadmin/IdeaProjects/mchnSelenium/out/artifacts/mchnSelenium_jar/mchnSelenium.jar
```

No matter when I seem to try I just get the following error output when trying to execute the jar file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at mac.chrome.Driver.<init>(Driver.java:30)
    at mac.chrome.Login.<init>(Login.java:8)
    at mac.chrome.TestLogin.main(TestLogin.java:7)
```

The property is being set by both ways (I can see it from the console log coming out). Not sure what's the issue here.

UPDATE:

I rebuilt my project using maven to build my dependencies and I am getting the exact same error. Funny how writing the tests takes less time than building a jar...

Comment: use absolute path to the driver.  (not sure that has anything to do with your Exception there though...)

Comment: The command line version uses the full path, changed it to the full path in System.setProperty() but alas no luck.